# How do you setup a Google Tag Manager JavaScript Variable to capture a parameter when the amount of ecommerce items is unknown?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I am attempting to setup Data Layer variables on Google Tag Manager to capture ecommerce data for our site. I can successfully capture the id, name, price, and quantity for a single item; but if I want to setup GTM to handle an unknown amount of items, I always seem to get 'undefined' for the return value when Previewing my changes. Here is an example dataLayer custom event that triggers successfully:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "AddToCart",
  ecommerce: {
    currency: "USD",
    items: [
      {
        item_id: "CTFBK",
        item_name: "Black Color Tissue Paper, 20x30\", Bulk 480 Sheet Flat Pack",
        price: 35.75,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        item_id: "18WK",
        item_name: "White Kraft Recycled Jewelry Boxes, 3.5x3.5x1\", 100 Pack, Fiber Fill",
        price: 49.2,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        item_id: "RBLBC",
        item_name: "Romantic Blooms Paper Gift Bag, Cub 8x4.75x10\", 250 Pack",
        price: 125,
        quantity: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 25
})
```

I created a DataLayer variable called 'ecommerce.items' that has the Data Layer Variable Name: 'ecommerce.items'. On Preview, this variable returns the below array:

```
[
  {
    item_id: "CTFBK",
    item_name: "Black Color Tissue Paper, 20x30\", Bulk 480 Sheet Fla" +
               "t Pack",
    price: 35.75,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    item_id: "18WK",
    item_name: "White Kraft Recycled Jewelry Boxes, 3.5x3.5x1\", 100 " +
               "Pack, Fiber Fill",
    price: 49.2,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    item_id: "RBLBC",
    item_name: "Romantic Blooms Paper Gift Bag, Cub 8x4.75x10\", 250 " +
               "Pack",
    price: 125,
    quantity: 3
  }
]
```

This is the latest JavaScript function that I inserted into the 'Global Variable Name' for the JavaScript Variable that should return an array of price values:

```
function() {   
    var itemPrices = [];   
    var items = {{ecommerce.items}};      
    if (items && items.length > 0) {     
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {       
            if (items[i].price) {         
                itemPrices.push(items[i].price);       
            }     
        }   
    }      
    return itemPrices; 
}
```

According to the Variables tab in the GTM Preview, this returns 'undefined'. What can I do differently to return the array of prices for each item?

[Screenshot showing undefined variables circled in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ZVk.png)

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you share more screenshot when it shows undefined?  Also you can try `Array.map` to return the price in a short way

Comment: @darrelltw I added a screenshot as a link to my post at the bottom. Other variables show up in this screenshot as defined, but it's because I use "ecommerce.items.0.price" or similar for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dataLayer from global object window from JavaScript.

```
var data = window.dataLayer
    if(dataLayer) {
    var itemPrices = [];   
        var items = data;      
        if (items && items.length > 0) {     
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {       
                if (items[i].price) {         
                    itemPrices.push(items[i].price);       
                }     
            }   
        }      
        return itemPrices; 
    }
```

But maybe the problem with undefined it's that dataLayer is not set yet when you run your function and you always get undefined.

Comment: I tried using the code you provided and have the same outcome. Added a screenshot of undefined values from my Preview Output to the bottom of my post if it helps. The "ecommerce.items" variable is defined as an array in the screenshot, so I'm not sure why I wouldn't be able to use it. I also tried renaming this variable and I get the same outcome.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is that you do not understand at what point the Data layer is formed. If you get uncertainty in your function, which is located in the “custom javascript” tag, then this only means that the data layer has not yet been formed and the data you need is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seemed to work fine for me.

If all your custom Javascript values return 'undefined', it might be blocked by the content security policy on your site.

[I had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75134097/cant-access-a-variable-from-another-variable-in-google-tag-manager)

[This user might provide some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576581/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-not-set-correctly-in-google-analyt)